# During visual studio compilation of a program I got error message. MSB3073 the command "npm run build-css exited with code 1."

Tags: c#, css, blazor

During visual studio compilation of a program I got error message. MSB3073  the command "npm run build-css exited with code 1."

[image]

How do I overcome this error? This is a c# program with Blazor framework.

Thank you!

D.

Answer (score -1):

you will need to go the the directory project of the solution and run this command to install node-sass that is simple:

npm i node-sass like this:

[image]

[image]

Done!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1